# How to pass selected value from POPUPLOV to Select query in Oracle-APEX

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I had created a popuplov and selected data from a shared component, I need to pass the selected value to a select query in the interactive report.

[image: Settings]

And I've select query in the interactive report, I need to pass the selected value to the select query in the report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add WHERE to your IR like

   SELECT ...
   FROM ...
   WHERE ... = :V_DC
2. Set "Page Items To Submit" property of IR to your PopupLOV name, so when IR refreshed by something, value of PopupLOV will be set into session state.
3. Add dynamic action on Change of PopupLOV

[image]

It means "Run this action when value of item P61011189_DEPT (PopupLOV) has changed".

4. Add one action to True branch of created Dynamic Action - Refresh IR Region.

[image]

It means "When Dynamic Action starts refresh Emps region".

You can check my example here: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54028:61011189

Comment: I Couldn't see the any options like "Page Items To Submit" under POPUP LOV. The same example, I'm looking for.

Comment: It's IR property, not PopopLOV. You have to set it to PoppuLOV element name

Comment: Wow. Fantastic. Is it possible to pass Multiple values from the popup lov to select query in the IR ?

Comment: hinotf, Can i see this background actions, https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54028:61011189

Comment: @Maya I've just added pics and description to answer, check it

Comment: can you help on this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62537507/oracle-apex-view-option-in-each-row-of-interactive-grid

Answer (score 0):

Use it in IR's query, in its `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
select ...
from ...
where data_center = :V_DC
```

As Popup LoV item doesn't have "Page action on selection" property which would enable to submit the page and "force" IR to refresh, one option is to create a button on that page which will do the same. So:

- choose value from Popup Lov
- push the button
- IR will refresh

That might be done differently, but I don't know how. Someone else might, though.

Comment: How do I push the button ?, Sorry I didn't understand this

Comment: I usually click on it.