# Oracle Apex - View option in each row of interactive grid

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I've a report table in Oracle Apex. I need to add a view button in each row, as the last column. On click on the view button, I need to popup a interactive grid /interactive report/classic report with some more details.

Hard to describe, please refer the attachment. I'm using apex version is 19.1.0.00.15

[image]

each rows are having different set of where clause in SQL statement .

[image]

Each row navigate to different pages, where i want to show the application/db/interface footprints

Comment: Hi. Your question shouldn't be a problem. Could you tell us what issue(s) you are encountering? What did you try? What doesn't work? What piece of information do you need to accomplish your goal?

Comment: Crate a modal page for the "more details", then create a new column of type link on the grid and make that link open the modal page, passing in the ID from the row.

Comment: @TonyAndrews, Hi Tony, You are suggesting, to create a page and link with the IG right ?

Comment: @Giliam - I need to create a View button in every row of my interactive gird,on click on the View , I've to populate another IG with another set of SQL. I'm not aware how to create the View button and how to link the popup to the view button.

Comment: @TonyAndrews - it was really helpful, I've created the link. now I can navigate to another page. 1. Challenge here is , each row is navigating to the same page. I need each rows to be point to different page.

Comment: @Maya That sounds wrong to me!  I would expect each link to go to the same page, passing in the ID from the record to a page item.  Then the new page would query tback the details belonging to that ID.  You should not be creating a page for Maya, another page for Eliza and so on - unless that is really what you want (which would be highly unusual!)

Comment: We are on same page @TonyAndrews. But the **ASK** is quiet unusual :(

Comment: @maya so what information/data does define to which page the button links to?

Comment: @Maya so it seems all you need is a hidden column in the report that specifies the relevant page for each person, and then the link can redirect to that page?

Comment: @Giliam, see the image in the question, each row has to perform different set of SQL statement. I don't know, is it possible :(.. thanks for the comments.

Comment: @TonyAndrews , In this case each rows going to perform different set of SQL statement.

Comment: @Maya What you could do is create a button/link for each of those situations. That will create lots of buttons/links, but based on some logic, you hide/show the buttons/links.